# How do I calculate the angle between two normalized vectors and an up direction?

Tags: math, vector, algebra

How would one go about calculating the angle of a vector versus an "up" direction while looking down the axis of another vector? To illustrate what I'm asking, I've drawn two diagrams:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cupWJ.jpg

In this image, you can see the general setup. The green arrows are the Y axis (up is positive, down is negative), the red arrows are the X axis (left is negative, right is positive), and the blue arrows are the Z axis (towards the screen is positive, away is negative).

The cyan and yellow arrows represent two normalized vectors (length = 1) centred around 0, 0, 0. The vectors can be anywhere in 3D space, I'm just using this as an example- the only thing guaranteed is that their length will always be 1 and the up direction will always be Vector(0, 1, 0).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWd1C.jpg

This is what I'm trying to figure out. I've oriented the camera so it points directly down the cyan arrow. I'm attempting to calculate the angle between the yellow arrow and the green (Y) axis while looking down the line specified by the cyan arrow.

I'm having troubles researching this on my own probably because I lack the vocabulary to adequately define my question (hence the diagrams). It seems like it might be possible to determine a rotation between the cyan arrow and a known axis, then rotate everything (including the yellow arrow) around the origin, at which point it's just a matter of using atan2() to determine the angle based on two coordinates of the yellow vector (ignoring the depth component), but I'm guessing there's probably a simpler way of doing things. What, if anything, might that be?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two vectors *v=(v1, v2, v3)* and *w=(w1, w2, w3)*, then their dot product is *v · w = v1 · w1 + v2 · w2 + v3 · w3*.  However another expression for their dot product is *v · w = |v| |w| cos a*, where *|v|* and *|w|* are the lengths of the two vectors, and *a* is the angle between them.

If you're representing these vectors as components (that is, the *(v1, v2, v3)*), then it's easy to calculate both their dot product and their respective lengths.  Then *cos a = v · w / (|v| |w|)*, and take arccos of that.

Working out rotations that would take one into the other is the *hard* way of doing this.

This is similar to various questions including [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229950/the-x-angle-between-two-3d-vectors) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150050/finding-signed-angle-between-vectors), but I think they make it sound more complicated than it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I'm not sure I understand. There's technically three vectors, and each have 3 components (X, Y, and Z, since they exist in 3D space). The first two vectors can be anywhere, but always have a length of 1 from the origin to the point specified by the vector. The third vector is the up direction, which is always 0, 1, 0 (points up on the Y axis). I don't need to calculate the angle between the two input vectors per say. I need to calculate the angle between the up direction (Y axis) and the second vector, while looking down the axis of the first vector to the origin.

Comment: (Continued) That's probably where I'm getting lost- everything I find on the internet is about finding the angle between the two vectors themselves, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. The second question you linked to seems to deal with 2D vectors, not 3D, though my original idea was essentially an attempt to transform the problem into 2D space.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean – I had indeed misunderstood you. You're looking for the angle between two vectors (yellow vector and the green Y axis) when projected into a plane perpendicular to a third vector (the cyan one). That's more fiddly than I have attention to address right now, I'm afraid, but that vocabulary might help you get started on searching for a solution.

Comment: That is correct, but the projection plane needs to be oriented so the Y axis aligns with the green arrow.