# How to get the y angle between 2 vectors in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, linear-algebra, angle, euler-angles

In Three.js I have 2 3d vectors and I want to find the x-axis and y-axis angle between them.

For the x-axis I found this

```
toDegrees(atan2(A.z, A.y) - atan2(B.z, B.y))
```

from
[The X angle between two 3D vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229950/the-x-angle-between-two-3d-vectors)

which works, but for y-axis, I am trying

```
toDegrees(atan2(A.z, A.x) - atan2(B.z, B.x))
```

but it gives me the wrong value. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: In what way is it wrong?  Magnitude?  Sign?  Can you give an example of two vectors, the result you expected, and the result you received?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vector3.angleTo](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=vector#api/en/math/Vector3.angleTo) directly, it will give you the angle in radians, as usual to math functions, here I printing it in degrees (multiplying by `180 degrees/pi rad= 1`)

```js
// notice that v1 is pointing to the x-axis direction.
const v1 = new THREE.Vector3(10,0,0);
const v2 = new THREE.Vector3(3,3,0);
const v3 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 50, 23);
// Alngle between v1 and v2
console.log(v1.angleTo(v2)*180/Math.PI)
// The operation is comutative
console.log(v2.angleTo(v1)*180/Math.PI)
// An example at 90 degree
console.log(v1.angleTo(v3)*180/Math.PI)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
```

This makes it possible to find angles to any direction, if you want angle to a plane for instance, it is given by `ans(a - 90)` where a is the angle in degrees to the normal vector of the plane.